# Swift TableView in ViewController In Navigation VC in Tab Bar: Cells won't populate with data from list

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar

I can't seem to populate my cells in my tableview with titles. I placed my tableview in my viewcontroller and embedded that in a navigation controller which is embedded in a tab bar view controller. The tableview loads but the cells don't have titles. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
            import Foundation
            import UIKit

            class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

                let tableData = ["One","Two","Three"]

                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
                    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00a5ff")
                    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 25)!]
                    self.title = "Interests"
                }

                func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
                {
                    return tableData.count
                }

                func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!,
                               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
                {

                    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")

                    cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

                    return cell
                }

                func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
                    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

                    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
                        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
                    }

                    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
                        return UIColor.gray
                    }

                    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
                    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

                    return UIColor(
                        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
                        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
                    )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your view controller as the datasource and call reloadData on your table view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#00a5ff")
  navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 25)!]
  self.title = "Interests"

  yourTableView.dataSource = self

  yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, there's so many mistakes in that code...

### First

Where's the UITableView property?
You need to declare

`@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

and connect it to the table view on the storyboard (or .xib file)

### Second

You need to adopt both table view protocols.

`UITableViewDatasource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

### Third

Set the ViewController as delegate

`tableView.delagate = self`
`tableView.datasource = self`

### Fourth

As mentioned above, you need to implement
`func numberOfSections`

datasource required method.

### Fifth

Everything should be working. If not, read a bit about UITableView.
Because I see that you are not Dequeuing cells on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You also need to implement "numberOfSections" dataSource method:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
  return 1
}
```

Other than that, you need to mark your ThirdViewController class as a UITableViewDataSource, and set dataSource property of the tableView to self:

```
ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource
{
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     ........
     yourTableView.dataSource = self


}
```